# Trouble relabelling indices

Tags: calculus, summation, proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to derive the time-dependent Schrödinger's equation (TDSE).

Starting with the definition of the [Unitary time evolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics)), $$\hat U(t)=e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}$$
where $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian operator.

The Taylor series expansion for an exponentiated operator, $\hat X$ is
$$e^{\hat X}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\hat X^n}{n!}$$

Therefore,
$$\hat U(t)=e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-i\hat H t}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\tag{1}$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to time and multiplying both sides by $i\hbar$,
$$\begin{align}i\hbar\frac{d\hat U(t)}{dt}=i\hbar\frac{d \left(e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}\right)}{dt}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{n}{n!}t^{n-1}{\hat H}^n\tag{2}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{t^{n-1}{\hat H}^n}{(n-1)!}\tag{3}\end{align}$$

In the last equality I simply used that $\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

As can be seen from the expression in $(2)$, the $n=0$ term is zero, so I need a summation starting from $n=1$, to do this, I let $k=n+1$

I purposely chose this new index so that when $n=0$, $k=1$, thus rewriting the summation in $(3)$ yields,
$$i\hbar\frac{d\,\hat U(t)}{dt}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^{k-1}\frac{t^{k-1-1}{\hat H}^{k-1}}{(k-2)!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^{k-1}\frac{t^{k-2}{\hat H}^{k-1}}{(k-2)!}\tag{?}$$

When I tried to shift the summation index in this expression all I was doing was following Jason Rose's video on changing the index of summation [which can be found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWFIdPtrRsI).

---

Now here is the problem, when the lecturer shifts the index in equation $(3)$ in lectures and the handwritten notes the lecturer writes $n\to n+1$,
$$\fbox{$\begin{align}i\hbar\frac{d\,\hat U(t)}{dt}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^{n+1}\frac{t^{n}{\hat H}^{n+1}}{n!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{t^{n}{\hat H}^{n+1}}{n!}\\&=\hat H \hat U(t)\end{align}$}$$

In going from the first to the second equality in the box above, $i\hbar\left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n$, and in going from the second to the third equality, the final expression only differs from equation $(1)$ by a single factor of $\hat H$.

Specializing the equation in the box above to the case of the Schrödinger picture, the states, $\lvert \psi(t)\rangle$ evolve in time, and so

$$i\hbar\frac{d \lvert\psi(t)\rangle}{dt}=\hat H \lvert \psi(t)\rangle\qquad\blacksquare\tag{TDSE}$$

---

I don't like the notation $n\to n+1$, as I think this leads to unnecessary confusion that can easily be avoided and I prefer to write $k=n+1$.

But with the exception of the letter $n$ in $n=n+1$ being replaced by $k=n+1$, this logic is identical to that given by the lecturer and so should give *exactly* the same answer.

So why does the summation index relabelling not work in my equation, $(\mathrm{?})$, despite the fact that I am doing the exact **same** thing as the lecturer (except with $n$ replaced by $k$)?

Comment: Well for a start (3) is not equal to (2), and indeed makes no sense. It's first term appears to involve $t^{-1}$ and then I notice it involves $(-1)!$. To correct (3) you  need to start the summation at $n=1$. And then you may write $k=n-1$ and rewrite with a sum starting at $k=0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for your comment. Are you sure $(2)\ne (3)$? I've confirmed it twice now, and it matches the lecture notes exactly, please see [this link](https://ibb.co/ryt8RMf) and then [this](https://ibb.co/XFYJHXH) link for the next step. Did the lecturer get it wrong? But why $k=n-1$? When $n=0$, $k=-1$ this makes no sense to me. The correct substitution to get the starting index equal to $1$ must be $k=n+1$, sorry if I'm still not understanding you.

Comment: (3) does not equal (2) because (3) makes no sense: look at it, what do you mean by $(-1)!$? where did $t^{-1}$ spring from. As I said to get a correct version of (3) you must start the summation at $n=1$. You then write $n=k+1$ and the sum starts at $k=0$. You're trying to go in the wrong direction, that's why you get these $(k-2)!$ from.

Comment: @ancientmathematician "Where did $t^{−1}$ spring from", well it is the power rule for differentiation, namely, $dt^n/dt=nt^{n-1}$, and secondly, what is the problem with $(-1)!$? This is defined and is $(-1)(-2)(-3)\cdots$.

Comment: OK, you are really confused. But the answer now posted sets out what I have been saying, you are going in reverse.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Very well then, I am really confused, but can you please answer the questions in my previous comment? Does it seem that $dt^n/dt\ne nt^{n-1}$ and $(-1)!\ne (-1)(-2)(-3)\cdots (-n)$?

Comment: First about the factorial: you are wrong. If it means anything it means $\infty$. But look: we are agreed, when you differentiate a constant you get $0$. You are confusing things enormously by writing instead of $0$ the (meaningless) $t^{-1}/(-1)!$. We just note that this term is zero, and start the summation at $n=1$. Then  the answer below explains how we manipulate this, we decide we want a sum starting at $0$ so we need to write $n=k+1$ etc etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hi there, yes, I see what you mean about the $(-1)!$ being undefined, so thanks for explaining that. The part you are questioning (eqn $(3)$) in my question is **exactly** the same as what my lecturer wrote (please see the links in an earlier comment), and this includes the $t^{n-1}$ which you say is meaningless. So my final question to you is: Is the lecturer making a mistake?

Comment: I think your lecturer is using a rough and ready shorthand.  You've said you're trying to be more careful (which I think is good). The way to do that is to note that the first term in (2) is zero, so omit it and write the sum starting at $n=1$, then write $k=n-1$ and get a sum starting at $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\ge0$, define$$u_n:=i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{n}{n!}t^{n-1}{\hat H}^n$$so $u_0=0$; for $n\ge1$, define$$v_n:=i\hbar \left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}\right)^n\frac{t^{n-1}{\hat H}^n}{(n-1)!}$$so $u_n=v_n$. Of course, $v_0$ is undefined. The correct manipulation is$$\sum_{n\ge0}u_n=\sum_{n\ge1}u_n=\sum_{n\ge1}v_n=\sum_{n\ge0}v_{n+1},$$or equivalently$$\sum_{k\ge1}u_{k-1}=\sum_{k\ge2}u_{k-1}=\sum_{k\ge2}v_{k-1}=\sum_{k\ge1}v_k.$$What you've attempted is more like $\sum_{n\ge0}u_n=\sum_{n\ge0}v_n$, which doesn't work regardless of your choice of letters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how strange, even though $\dfrac{n}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$ when $n=0$ the LHS, $\dfrac{0}{0!}=0$, yet the RHS is $\dfrac{1}{(0-1)!}$ and undefined. That being the case, does this mean that $\dfrac{n}{n!}\ne\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$?

Comment: @skynet The trouble with claiming $1/(-1)!=0$ is you're saying $1=0!=0x,\,1/x=0$ for some quantity $x$ you name $(-1)!$, but $0x=1$ leads to contradictions in the usual rules of arithmetic. $(-1)!$ _is undefined_. In particular, the manipulation$$\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{n}{\prod_{k=1}^nk}=\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$only makes sense if $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k$ has $n-1$ factors, i.e. $n\ge1$. You can't cancel $n$ from $\prod_{k=1}^nk$ if that product is empty (which happens when $n\ge0$), as then $n$ isn't a factor of it.